# Extract variable from spring webflux reactive pipeline

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I am working on reactive streams using Spring webflux. I want to extract a variable(`name`) from the middle of the reactive pipeline and use it in a different place as follows.

```
public class Example {

    public Mono<String> test() {
        String name;

        return Mono.just("some random string")
                    .map(s -> {
                        name = s.toUpperCase(); 
                        return name;
                    }).map(...)
                      .map(...)
                      .flatMap(...)
                      .map(...)
                      .map(result -> result+name)
                      .doOnSuccess(res -> asyncPublish(name));
     
     public void asyncPublish(String name) {
        // logic to write to a Messaging queue asynchronously
     }
    }
}
```

The above code is not working. This is a contrived example but shows what I want to achieve.

**Note:** I don't want to use multiple `zip` operators just to bring the `name` all the way to the last map where I want to use it. Is there a way I can store it in a variable as shown above and then use it somewhere else whereever I need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use for example a [Tuple2](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/util/function/Tuple2.html) to pass the value of `name` along with the modified data through the chain.

```
return Mono.just("some random string")
            .map(s -> s.toUpperCase())
            .map(s -> Tuples.of(s, x(s))) // given that x(s) is the transformation of this map statement
            .map(...) // keeping Tuple with the value of `name` in the first slot...
            .flatMap(...) // keeping Tuple with the value of `name` in the first slot...
            .map(resultTuple -> Tuples.of(resultTuple.getT1(), resultTuple.getT2() + resultTuple.getT1()) // keeping Tuple with the value of `name` in the first slot...
            .doOnSuccess(resultTuple -> asyncPublish(resultTuple.getT1()))
            .map(resultTuple -> resultTuple.getT2()); // in case that the returned Mono should contain the modified value...
```

`Tuples` is from the package `reactor.util.function` and part of reactor-core.

Another way (without passing the value through the chain using Tuples) could be to use [`AtomicReference`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html) (but I still think that the Tuple way is cleaner). The AtomicReference way might look like this:

```
public Mono<String> test() {
    final AtomicReference<String> nameRef = new AtomicReference<>();

    return Mono.just("some random string")
                .map(s -> {
                    final String name = s.toUpperCase(); 
                    nameRef.set(name);
                    return name;
                }).map(...)
                  .map(...)
                  .flatMap(...)
                  .map(...)
                  .map(result -> result+nameRef.get())
                  .doOnSuccess(res -> asyncPublish(nameRef.get()));
 
 public void asyncPublish(String name) {
    // logic to write to a Messaging queue asynchronously
 }
}
```

Comment: But what if I want to use the variable in doOnSuccess()? Let me update the post as well

Comment: @justAnotherDev I updated my answer accordingly. You should still be able to utilize the Tuple approach for this as shown in the sample code contained in my answer.

Comment: Cool. Also, is there any other way that doesnt use Tuples? I'm trying to avoid Tuple's as in the pipeline I will endup using `tupleVariable.getT1()` everywhere else.

Comment: @justAnotherDev AtomicReference could be an alternative (I added an example in my answer). But maybe the Tuple way is still the more clean solution.

Comment: Thanks. I like both of your solutions actually. The reason for why I think tuples might not be a good idea is if we have a lot of operators in the reactive pipeline, we will have to use the `tuple.getT1()` or `tuple.getT2()` in multiple places. Lets say we have 10 operators and only 1 of them needs `tuple.getT2()`, in this case we end up writing a lot of unnecessary `tuple.getT1()` where we could directly use the `value` instead of a `tuple`.

Comment: Also, does this `AtomicReference` approach have any caveats?